# Javascript returning strange value

Tags: javascript

I was testing a function out to see what happens when it's parameters are `null` and decided to put an else statement with it.  To my surprise, it did not log the parameters that I have passed, it's logging something else entirely.  Maybe someone can shed some light on this, here's the code:

```
function testing(o) {
    if (!o) {
        return "Sorry, looks like you need to pass an argument.."
    } else {
        return o;
    }
}

console.log(testing(02034));
//logs 1052
```

What's going on here?

Comment: It has to do with the number you put in. It started with a 0 which is in base 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Javascript, like other languages, starting a number with 0 would indicate it's base 8 (Octal).

Thus, `02034` in base 8 = 1052 in base 10 (decimal).

Comment: it's the system of counting we'd use if we arbitrarily had 8 fingers instead of 10 :)

Comment: @JeremyWeir That makes sense.  Also, this answer helped me, will be accepting once I can.

Comment: Run it though `parseInt` as a string with the second parameter indicating its base (I assume you're talking about user input)? e.g. `parseInt("0123", 10) = 123` but `parseInt("0123") = 83`.

Answer (score 3):

The leading "0" is causing JavaScript to read the value as an [Octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number. When you print it to the console, it is being converted back to it's decimal representation.

Comment: It's not fair, the ellapsed time between the answers is not that much, could be that @Jay just answered firts

Comment: @h3nr1x - Answering questions in Stack Overflow is like a race - The faster, the winner. `:/`

Comment: @h3nr1x it was a 5 minute difference on a simple paragraph answer. We can rule that option out

Answer (score 2):

That notation is called an [octal integer literal](https://www.google.com/search?q=octal%20integer%20literal)